# Downloading blocks of data from census, how to wrtie to multiple csvs to not exceed memory

Tags: python, pandas, census

Suppose I have a list of api keys I am downloading from the census data

Example:

```
variable_list = [
'B08006_017E',
'B08016_002E',
'B08016_003E',
'B08016_004E',
...
]
```

Now given memory constraints for putting this data onto one csv file. I want to create a way in which I place blocks of 100 variables from the variable list onto a number of csv files. For example, if I have 200 variables than I would have 2 csv files of the first 100 and one with the second 100 varaibles. I hope that is clear.

This is how I am currently downloading the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import censusdata
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('display.precision', 2)
#import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
import censusgeocode as cg
import numpy as np
from numbers import Number
import plotly
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
import requests
import pandas
import geopandas
import json
import math
from haversine import haversine
from ipfn import ipfn
import networkx
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import patheffects
from shapely.geometry import LineString, MultiLineString

variable_list1 = [
'B08006_017E',
'B08016_002E'
'B08016_003E',
'B08016_004E'
]

all_variable_lists = [variable_list1]
print(len(all_variable_lists[0]))
#2) For each year, download the relevant variables for each tract
def download_year(year,variable_list,State,County,Tract):
    df = censusdata.download('acs5', year, censusdata.censusgeo([('state',State),('county',County),('tract',Tract)]), variable_list, key = 'e39a53c23358c749629da6f31d8f03878d4088d6')
    df['Year']=str(year)
    return df
#3) Define function to download for a single year and state 
def callback_arg(i,variable_list,year):
    try:        
        print('Downloading - ',year,'State', i,' of 57')
        if i<10:
            df = download_year(year,variable_list,'0'+str(i),'*','*')
            return df
        if i==51:
            df = download_year(year,variable_list,str(i),'*','*')
            return df
        else:
            df = download_year(year,variable_list,str(i),'*','*')
            return df
    except:
        pass

#3) Function to download for all states and all years, do some slight formatting
def download_all_data(variable_list,max_year):
    df=download_year(2012,variable_list,'01','*','*')
    for year in range(2012,max_year+1):
        if year == 2012:
            for i in range(0,57):
                df=df.append(callback_arg(i,variable_list,year))
        else: 
            for i in range(0,57):
                df=df.append(callback_arg(i,variable_list,year))
    df2=df.reset_index()
    df2=df2.rename(columns = {"index": "Location+Type"}).astype(str)
    df2['state']=df2["Location+Type"].str.split(':').str[0].str.split(', ').str[2]
    df2['Census_tract']=df2["Location+Type"].str.split(':').str[0].str.split(',').str[0].str.split(' ').str[2][0]
    df2['County_name']=df2["Location+Type"].str.split(':').str[0].str.split(', ').str[1]
    return(df2)
#4) Some slight formatting
def write_to_csv(df2,name = 'test'):
    df2.to_csv(name)
#5) The line below is commented out, but should run the entire download sequence
def write_to_csv(df, ide):
    df.to_csv('test' + str(ide) + '.csv')

list_of_dfs = []
for var_list in all_variable_lists:
    list_of_dfs.append(download_all_data(var_list, 2012))
x1 = list_of_dfs[0].reset_index()
# x3 = pd.merge(x1,x2, on=['index','Location+Type','Year','state','Census_tract','County_name'])
write_to_csv(x1,1)
```

If anyone can give me some ideas on how to achieve what I want this would greatly help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're already chunking the variable_lists here:

```py
for var_list in all_variable_lists:
    list_of_dfs.append(download_all_data(var_list, 2012))
```

Just make sure each `var_list` has only 100 items. Then chunk the csv writing in the same way, using `enumerate` to increment the index for filename:

```py
for index, out_list in enumerate(list_of_dfs):
    write_to_csv(out_list.reset_index(),index)
```

If you're just looking to break up the final output at write time:

```py
for index, out_list in enumerate(np.array_split(x1, 100)):
    write_to_csv(out_list,index)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but if I have say 200 items I need to download how do I go in 100 blocks to output to excel?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx I added another code block which I think is what you're asking for

Comment: When we write out to a csv don't we need to make a naming mechanism or something?

Comment: You handle that in this line: `df.to_csv('test' + str(ide) + '.csv')`